# How to delete all records from a table

Tags: excel, vba

I want to clear all records from an excel table I created (The table is just a list of rows and columns which have been bordered). At the moment using the code below I am able to produce a little validation where one rows from 47 or higher can be deleted. But this only deletes one row at a time when I click a button:

```
Sub Clear1st()

Dim iRet1 As Integer
Dim iRet2 As Integer
Dim iRet3 As Integer
Dim strPrompt1 As String
Dim strPrompt2 As String
Dim strPrompt3 As String
Dim strTitle1 As String
Dim strTitle2 As String
Dim strTitle3 As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect

    strPrompt1 = "Only rows 47 and higher may be cleared"
    strTitle1 = "Deletion Error"
    strPrompt2 = "Are you sure you want to clear all records?"
    strTitle2 = "Clear Records Confirmation"
    strPrompt3 = "There is no recods to clear."
    strTitle3 = "Data Missing"

    If Selection.Row <= 46 Then
    iRet1 = MsgBox(strPrompt1, vbOKOnly, strTitle1)
        If iRet1 = vbOKOnly Then
       Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    If Application.CountA(ActiveCell.EntireRow) = 0 Then
        ElseIf Selection.Row < 47 Then
    iRet3 = MsgBox(strPrompt3, vbOKOnly, strTitle3)
        If Ret3 = vbOKOnly Then
       Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    If Selection.Row >= 47 Then
    iRet2 = MsgBox(strPrompt2, vbYesNo, strTitle2)
        If iRet2 = vbNo Then
       Exit Sub
    Else
        If iRet2 = vbYes Then

    Selection.EntireRow.Delete

    End If
        End If
            End If

    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
        , AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
        AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, _
        AllowUsingPivotTables:=True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

What my question is what I can't seem to figure out to do is that I want it to delete all records from the table when I click on the button.

So if the user clicks on the button, from rows 47 onwards between columns J-M, it will delete all rows. But how am I able to get it to delete all records at once? Like I said the table rows are just borders to make it look like rows (J2:M2) is where it grabs a bordered row,copies it and adds it to the table.

Here is a screenshot on what a table could look like (number of rows in a table varies but screenshot goes from 47 to 71):

http://www.dropviewer.com/v.php?i=527a891790213.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I completely understand the results you want, but replacing your `Selection.EntireRow.Delete` statement with something like this should help:

```
    With ActiveSheet
       Rows("47:" & .Rows.Count).Delete
    End With
```

Comment: Hi, you are very close, (95% there), you have managed to clear the table. But only issue is lets say I enter something directly below the table (not in the table), If I click on the button, it removes not only all the table rows but also all the content underneath the table. That is why I need to Row.Count to somehow be able to go only up to the last table row (like I said each table row has a border so can we some how use this to determine the last table row)?